# error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: docker, meteor, alpine-linux, libstdc++

I'm trying to create a `meteor-alpine` image like this:
- start from the [alpine](https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine) image
- install tools like `curl`, `bash`, etc
- install meteor: `curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh`
- after that, when I try to run this command: `meteor -v`, I got this error: `error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`
full details:

```
/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.8.1.ani1yi.p0f9s++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried to install packages like `g++` and `libstdc++` but they didn't help.

Comment: It seems Meteor needs glibc, rather than Alpine's musl libc, so you'll need a glibc comparability layer - `libc6-compact` may do. Or, use one of the available Meteor Alpine images: https://hub.docker.com/r/staeke/meteor-alpine, https://github.com/staeke/meteor-alpine